# Treeview mouse position python

Tags: python, treeview, python-2.x, ttk

I'm not really sure whether this question has been asked before, as it seems to be too trivial to be new, however I've been looking around for an hour now and have not found anything

I'm using ttk Treeview to display and analyze a table. For a given function I want to be able to identify the exact cell which has been double clicked (row and column). While it's easy to find the row, I can't find the column as the mouse position is always show relative to the screen, not relative to Treeview with winfo_pointerx(). Also I cannot get event.x to work...

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import utils

class AudiDataList():

    def __init__(self, i_root, i_header, i_data, i_types):
        self.root = i_root

        f1 = ttk.Frame(root)
        f1.pack()
        t1 = ttk.Treeview(f1, columns=i_header, show="headings")
        t1.pack()

        for col in i_header:
            t1.heading(col, text=col.title())
        for item in i_data:
            t1.insert('', 'end', values=item, tags = ('item',))
        t1.tag_bind('item', "<Double-Button-1>", callback=lambda c=col: self.filter(t1, c, 0, i_types, i_header))

    def filter(self, tree, col, descending, i_types, i_header):
        print "Row: ", tree.focus()
        print "X-position", tree.winfo_pointerx()
        print "Column: ??? ",tree.identify_column(tree.winfo_pointerx())


header = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
datentypen = ['text', 'money', 'int']
data = [
('a', '1,00', 1) ,
('a', '2,00', 2) ,
('b', '12,10', 3) ,
('c', '2,10', 4) ,
('b', '3,00', 5)]

root = Tk()
Auditable = AudiDataList(root, header, data, datentypen)

root.mainloop()
```

I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to combine few tricks to resolve your problem.

First, you will need to use [`winfo_pointerxy()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html). This returns  a tuple `(x , y)` containing the coordinates of the mouse pointer relative to your `tree` 's root window.

You need then to use the first element of this tuple, `winfo_pointerxy()[0]`, to call  [`identify_column()`](http://acm2014.cct.lsu.edu/localdoc/python-3.4.2rc1-docs-html/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.identify_column) method from which you substract [`winfo_rootx()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_rootx-method) (to resolve the problem of shifting the window).

But you need to be careful because the tuple returned by `winfo_pointerxy()` is of type `<type 'unicode'>`. So you will need, for example, to `import re` in order to use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) so that you can replace data in form `#1` to integer  `1`.

This means your `filter()` method will now look like this:

```
     def filter(self, tree, col, descending, i_types, i_header):               
         print 'Row: {} & Column: {} '.format(re.sub('I00','',str(tree.identify_row(tree.winfo_pointerxy()[1]-tree.winfo_rooty()))),re.sub(r'#','',str(tree.identify_column(tree.winfo_pointerxy()[0]-tree.winfo_rootx()))))
```

## Full program

So here is the full program:

```
'''
Created on Apr 24, 2016

@author: billal begueradj
'''
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import re

class AudiDataList():

    def __init__(self, i_root, i_header, i_data, i_types):
        self.root = i_root

        f1 = ttk.Frame(root)
        f1.pack()
        t1 = ttk.Treeview(f1, columns=i_header, show="headings")
        t1.pack()

        for col in i_header:
            t1.heading(col, text=col.title())
        for item in i_data:
            t1.insert('', 'end', values=item, tags = ('item',))
        t1.tag_bind('item', "<Double-Button-1>", callback=lambda c=col: self.filter(t1, c, 0, i_types, i_header))

         def filter(self, tree, col, descending, i_types, i_header):               
             print 'Row: {} & Column: {} '.format(re.sub('I00','',str(tree.identify_row(tree.winfo_pointerxy()[1]-tree.winfo_rooty()))),re.sub(r'#','',str(tree.identify_column(tree.winfo_pointerxy()[0]-tree.winfo_rootx())))) 

header = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
datentypen = ['text', 'money', 'int']
data = [
('a', '1,00', 1) ,
('a', '2,00', 2) ,
('b', '12,10', 3) ,
('c', '2,10', 4) ,
('b', '3,00', 5)]

root = Tk()
Auditable = AudiDataList(root, header, data, datentypen)

root.mainloop()
```

## Demo

Here is a screenshot of the running program:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Billal! I tried it and it works. However, I'll need now to spend some to find out why...

Comment: Oops. That was too quick.... same problem as before. If I shift the window to the right of the screen, then Col1 become Col3 and Col3 becomes <empty>, i.e. winpointer_xy() just like winfo_pointerx() seems to return a mouse position relative to the screen, not relative to the window.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I did not  shift the window on the screen, so I did not notice the problem you mentioned. I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Guess I found it.
The problem was that tree.winfo_pointerx() does not return the position relative to Treeview, but rather relative to the screen.
Also, tree.winfo_x() always returns zero.
However, subtracting self.root.winfo_x() from tree.winfo_pointerx() does the job.

In any case, re is needed for converion of coordinates.

Got to go now, if you need a snippet, I'll post that later.

Comment: In the end it turned out to be:

Comment: x = tree.winfo_pointerxy()[] - self.root.winfo_rootx() - f1.winfo_x().  This is because the frame f1 in the final implementation is at the right side of a Paned Window. What really got me confused in the process of implementing this was that the methods to find the x-Position did not work with all objects.